# vis.js timeline auto scroll function

Tags: scroll, vis.js, autoscroll, vis.js-timeline

I have gotten into a small issue I can't seam to wrap my head around, and I hope for some guidesnes from you folks.

I have a timeline with a bunch of groups and subgroups, and the height of the timeline is now bigger than the height of the monitor showing it.

And that is fine it can be scrolled using the scroll wheel on the mouse, however as it is ment to be just a timeline on a wall mounted screen it would be cool if I could make an autoscroll function, that scroll the timeline up and down in a given timeframe.

Unfortunatly I can't figure out where to implement it to make it work.

I have the following code to make a div scroll ( and have tried diffrent ways to make it do it in the vis.js code, but so far no luck )

if anyone knows of a way to make it scroll up and down in a given timeframe i would really appreciate the help.

```
<script language="javascript">
ScrollRate = 1;

function scrollDiv_init() {
    //this can be a class also. 
    DivElmnt = document.getElementById('MyDivName');
    ReachedMaxScroll = false;

    DivElmnt.scrollTop = 0;
    PreviousScrollTop  = 0;

    ScrollInterval = setInterval('scrollDiv()', ScrollRate);
}

function scrollDiv() {

    if (!ReachedMaxScroll) {
        DivElmnt.scrollTop = PreviousScrollTop;
        PreviousScrollTop++;

        ReachedMaxScroll = DivElmnt.scrollTop >= (DivElmnt.scrollHeight - DivElmnt.offsetHeight);
    }
    else {
        ReachedMaxScroll = (DivElmnt.scrollTop == 0) ? false : true;

        DivElmnt.scrollTop = PreviousScrollTop;
        PreviousScrollTop--;
    }
}

function pauseDiv() {
    clearInterval(ScrollInterval);
}

function resumeDiv() {
    PreviousScrollTop = DivElmnt.scrollTop;
    ScrollInterval    = setInterval('scrollDiv()', ScrollRate);
}
</script>
```

Comment: So basically you don't know how to make vis.js timeline scroll programmatically, right?

Comment: yes i belive so.

as it is now the Timeline is to high for my monitor, and you need to scroll useing the mouse, or drag it to show the rest.

and that is fine for the user that sits at the pc and useing it, but my plan was to show it on a bigscreen and for that, it would be more usefull to have a automatic scroll function so it will show all items in the timeline, and not just the few that fits with in the screen.

Comment: Ah, I see. Could you please create a working snippet/jsFiddle so that I can play around and probably help with it? Not necessarily with your data, you can just mock up some data so that it overflows the height

Comment: I can't get the JsFiddle to work, it wont load up the timeline, i will see if i can figure out why ( i am new to jsFiddel ) 

how ever i have a link to the timeline exsample where it shows kind a my problem.

http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/other/verticalScroll.html

if you see the the bottom timeline ( the one i use ) i need the timeline to autoscroll up and down to show  all of the trucks once in a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the only tricky part I can see about scrolling timeline at http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/other/verticalScroll.html is that you have to scroll *certain element*, not the container of the timeline. If you use inspector to find the element with the scrollbar, you'll probably be surprised to see this:

[image]

Indeed, if I apply scrolling to that element

```
 var scrollerElement = document.querySelector('#mytimeline1 div.vis-panel.vis-left.vis-vertical-scroll');
 scrollerElement.scrollTop = 100;
```

the timeline gets scrolled vertically. By the way, the `vis-vertical-scroll` class suggests that we are on the right way. Actually, you should probably use a shorter selector instead:

```
 var scrollerElement = document.querySelector('#mytimeline1 .vis-vertical-scroll');
```

You can try this via browser console on that page. I think this should be enough for you to implement the desired autoscrolling.